# Android UI can be created by code *AND* XML?

Tags: android, view

I am having trouble grasping a certain concept in Android UI design. The book I am referring to first uses the usual technique that Java programmers use to create UIs and that is to to create containers and add UI components to them and nest them as necessary.

Now, the book introduces a new concept where the entire UI was created using an XML file. The code is pasted below:

```
package com.oreilly.android.intro;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
/**
* Android UI demo program
*/
public class AndroidDemo extends Activity {
  private LinearLayout root;
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
   super.onCreate(state);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
 }
}
```

so basically, I can use **any** of them ?

Comment: Yes, views can be defined in XML or in code. XML is generally preferred for re-usability and flexibility but often you can do more in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer,yes, you can use either approach. However, there are some limitations to each such as there are `layout` properties that must be set in xml if you want to use them. I can't think of what any are off-hand but I can look them up.

For the most part, creating the `layouts` is much simpler to do in xml but you do have the option of setting `Views` and `layouts` in Java if you need to such as creating an unknown number of `Buttons` depending on some user-defined variable.

When you create your `UI` in xml then you `inflate` it in your Java code. This is normally done in `onCreate()` using

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

as you see in your example. But it can also be done with an [inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

The thing to remember here is to inflate your `layout`, using either method, before trying to initialize any `views` in the `layout` or you will get a `NPE` when trying to call a method on a `View` defined before inflating the `layout` it is contained in.

A correct way

```
**Examples of inflating views/layouts correctly**
    Button mBtn;
    public class AndroidDemo extends Activity {
  private LinearLayout root;
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
   super.onCreate(state);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

   btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId); // Button is initialized after inflating the layout
 }
}
```

Incorrect way

```
    public class AndroidDemo extends Activity {
  private LinearLayout root;
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
   super.onCreate(state);
   Button mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);  // Button is initialized before inflating layout which will return null
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
}
}
```

I added the above example because I have seen a lot of people make that mistake. So don't do it...you've been warned! :)

Comment: I am a beginner at Android, as you can tell. I must focus *most* of my attention to using XML rather than Java for UI design?

Comment: I would say so. Start with that and as you learn more then you will start to use Java for it in certain circumstances

Comment: so professional devs mix and match java and xm depending on what the view is doing, right ? :)

Comment: Also, I would make sure you know xml and use that more than relying on the GUI editor. IMHO, doing it in xml is easier and more flexible.

Comment: I know xml fairly well. Just a question: **root** will take up all of the space on the screen. right ? :)
*that is: no matter how big the phone screen is, root will take up the entire space. be it 1280x800 or 640x480*

Comment: Not necessarily. `root` here is a variable name that references the `LinearLayout` with `id` of `root` declared in your xml. It depends on what that `Layout`s `height` and `width` are set to

Comment: dammit .. the book I am using is so convoluted. I am 171 pages down and it does not *explain* how to build views. :-P

Comment: Typically you will set your "root" `layout` in your xml with these properties 'android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"' which will take up the entire screen then you can have child `layout`s and `view`s beneath that

Comment: I would burn that book and stick to [The Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)  :P You can also find some other good tutorials online

Comment: Already bought it. Cant burn it. My family will think I am doing some computer witchcraft :-D

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant [This One](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html). Depending on your knowledge, you may be able to skip some of it but its a good place to get started

Comment: I will use book + website cause book has a lot of technical knowledge that is not on the site :-) Thanks for the help ! If you have time, [see this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gf1h2PMPCAo)

Comment: That's a good idea. Also, when you run into trouble, SO has a lot of good answers. I will check it out soon.

Comment: what is the `@+id` when giving an element an ID ?

Comment: Its like declaring a variable. It tells Android to give that `View`/`Layout` an `id` and add it to the `resources` file so you can access it in Java. If it is something in the Android framework then you don't need the `+` because it already exists.

Comment: what happens if I decide to skip the `@+id` and just give it an id ?? it wont be added to `resources` file ?

Comment: Yes and you won't be able to access it...if it even compiles that way, not sure. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but the two are interchangeable.
Most of the time your UI will be done via xml. In some cases though, the ui is heavily dependent of the data, so you may need to dynamically generate it.

It basically comes down to whichever is easiest for you at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
But is preferable to use xml, it is more powerful, easier and will separate layout from your code.
Take a look at the docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html